# How do I limit FPS in games?

Tags: nvidia

Like the title says, I want to know if I can do that on Ubuntu. (On Windows, I used to do it using NVIDIA Inspector.)

I have a Lenovo Y580, with Intel 4000HD and GTX 660M.

I am talking about limiting to 30fps or 45. Thank you.

Edit :- but i know about vsync the thing is that i want to do that because i downvolted my gpu and downclocked it too @V0.85 (@810/2000) so when i play dota its fine it stays 60fps but when i play games like "interstellar marines" my fps keeps dropping and jumping and i hate that and the reason i downvolted my gpu is my labtop become too hot 90+C while gaming so yeah, i tried re paste many times dunno whats wrong it never works, again thank you :)